# Question about an exercise (Bjarnes PPP book)

Tags: c++

Why do when i input strings separated by whitespace (outside a while loop) and i try to print them on the screen only the first one i typed appears and When inside this while loop (see code) it prints all of them one by one?

```
//this one prints the strings one by one
    string current;

while (cin >> current) {
        cout  << current << " \n";
}


//this one only prints the first one the user types
string current;
cin >> current;
cout << current << " \n";
```

Comment: Outside the loop you read one string and printed it. It doesn't matter how many you typed, there is only one input statement. That's what the loop is for, to input them all.

Comment: What you type is not the same as what the program reads. You could write a program that reads one character, doesn't matter if you then type 50 characters, only one is going to get read. It's the same with your program above, it reads one string, doesn't matter if you then type more than one string, only the first string will get read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the way `cin` operates by default. It skips over any whitespace, reads until the next whitespace, and returns that string. If you enter:

```
    testing cin input
```

you need to execute `cin` three times to get each of the words. That is what is happening in the `while` loop.

I mention "by default" because you can change the behavior to not skip whitespace.

Comment: Oh i see. I think i got it. Thanks.

Comment: @rm1948 so when i hit enter with "testing cin input" it will execute the (cin >> current) command in the while loop for every string i typed in, right?

Comment: That is true but if you enter "try this" you'll get "try" and then "this" output. Cin will read the two of them in sequence after you press 'enter'.